# Ternary operators in ruby

Tags: ruby

Seems like there should be a better way to do this:

```
def some_method(argument = 'foo')
  bar = argument == 'foo' ? 'foo' : "#{argument.to_s}_foo"

  # ... do things with bar ...
end
```

Any ideas? I've also played around with

```
bar = ("#{argument}_" if argument != 'foo').to_s + argument
```

but if anything that seems more complicated

Comment: Can `argument` become `'foo'` other than by default? Is `argument` always a string?

Comment: Please define "better". What is the specific problem you see with the first solution?

Comment: @RenatoZannon Looking for good style..if any I think..

Comment: You will be missing potentially good answers if you do not appear back to the site and respond to the comments.

Comment: If this is something you do commonly, I would just make this logic its own function.

Comment: Argument can be set to anything by default, I'm defining the function. Better as in cleaner. Out of town for the weekend or I would not have missed this. This is just something for this one function, not something commonly done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your example, you don't seem to need different variables for `foo` and `argument` at all (that would be different if you need them both later, but from your example it doesn't seem like it).

A simplification would be:

```
def some_method(bar = 'foo')
  unless bar == 'foo'
    bar = "#{bar}_foo"
  end

  # Do things with bar
end
```

Of course, you can do the `unless` inline if you prefer:

```
bar = "#{bar}_foo" unless bar == 'foo'
```

Side note: You don't need to call `to_s` when interpolating. Ruby will do that for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I needed both variables. Good note about the to_s though, didn't know!

Comment: I'll mess around with this as a solution, so I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

If `argument` in your code does not become `"foo"` other than by default, then you can do:

```
def some_method *argument
  bar = [*argument, "foo"].join("_")
  ...
end
```

Comment: This changes the signature of the method, since it can now be called with multiple arguments. I suppose you meant `argument = nil` on the method declaration?

Comment: @RenatoZannon No I didn't. If I do `argument = nil`, then that will not give `bar = "_foo"` any more as the original did, when `nil` is explicitly given as an argument. As long as arguments that were valid to the original (one or none arguments) are given, difference in the arity does not matter.

Comment: True, I didn't see that. I guess you could remove the splat and `#compact` the array, but that wouldn't be simpler than the ternary anymore ;) I would argue that the answer could use a note about the change in arity, though.